# What does the es5 environment created by babel-polyfill do?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-module-loader

From the docs it says babel-polyfill creates a es5 environment, but what does an environment do exactly? Does this have anything to do with how import and exporting works? My understanding is that import and exporting modules is part of es6 so it's not native to browsers, thus babel-polyfill transcompiles that some feature of es5 that does importing and exporting.

Comment: Does it say ES5 environment or ES6 environment? It would be helpful if you could link the docs you're reading so we have some context.

Comment: It says *This will **emulate** a full ES2015 environment*, not *create* one. It also goes on to explain what the Polyfill does. It does not handle syntax changes, these are handled by the plugins you use when running Babel. The [Learn ES2015](http://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#modules) page explains how it transforms import/export code depending on what configuration you require (AMD/CommonJS/Globals,etc)